Using DiscretePlot3D, why are the edges of 3D bars distorted?
Using DiscretePlot3D,why the edge of 3d Bars plotted are disordered?
I am so confusing .
You can see that at the top of the columns, the lines at the edges are distorted, which looks very unpleasant
Crosstalk = {{0.01, 0.002137962, 0.016218101, 0.000870964, 
   0.005623413, 0.03801894, 1}, {0.011220185, 0.020417379, 
   0.016595869, 0.001318257, 0.001479108, 1, 
   0.005495409}, {0.001348963, 0.000812831, 0.000446684, 0.000323594, 
   1, 0.001258925, 0.000123027}, {0.003090295, 0.003467369, 
   0.001513561, 1, 0.005128614, 0.001071519, 
   0.000263027}, {0.00020893, 0.000186209, 1, 0.000213796, 0.00042658,
    0.00128825, 0.00616595}, {0.007762471, 1, 0.011481536, 
   0.001174898, 0.003162278, 0.019054607, 0.003715352}, {1, 
   0.033113112, 0.004365158, 0.000776247, 0.00676083, 0.005754399, 
   0.002344229}}

colorSettings = {{0., CMYKColor[.18, .39, .045, .28]}, {0.2, 
   CMYKColor[.1, .4, 0, .28]}, {0.5, CMYKColor[.32, .39, 0, .28]}}

myPlot = 
 DiscretePlot3D[
  Crosstalk[[Mass, Radius]], {Mass, 1, 7}, {Radius, 1, 7}, 
  ColorFunction -> (Blend[colorSettings, #3] &), 
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
  ExtentSize -> 0.3,(*ExtentElementFunction->"PlaneFadingCube",*)
  PlotStyle -> 
   Directive[Opacity[0.8, White], 
    EdgeForm[{RGBColor[0, 0, 0], Thickness[0.001]}]], 
  BoxRatios -> {1, 1, 0.618*0.3}, 
  ImagePadding -> {{30, 20}, {30, 20}}, 
  AxesEdge -> {{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {-1, -1}}, 
  PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 1}}, 
  AxesLabel -> {Style["Modes", 12, Bold, Black], 
    Style["Modes", 12, Bold, Black], 
    Rotate[Style["Normalized Crosstalk", 12, Bold, Black], 3.14/2]}, 
  Ticks -> {{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {0, 0.25, 
     0.5, 0.75, 1}}, 
  TicksStyle -> {{12, Bold}, {12, Bold}, {12, Bold}}, 
  PlotLabel -> "Crosstalk between different Modes", ImageSize -> 700, 
  ScalingFunctions -> "Linear", Boxed -> False, 
  BoxStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.001]]]



Does changing PlotRange -> {All, All, {0, 1.1}} help?

Thank you veryveryvery much !! it works !  You are genius!!! Love
